# Conan install --build doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, c++, cmake, conan

I am trying to run `conan install` with force build flag in order to download sources then build them on my local machine using the following command:

```
conan install <conanfilePath> -s compiler="Visual Studio" -s compiler.version=8 --build
```

From what I read on [this link](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/install.html)
Conan is supposed to run the `source()` and `build()` among a bunch of `conanfile.py` methods.

When I run the command it seems like it does not operate the `source()` method, which runs fine when I'm running it alone using `conan source` command and consequentially the `build()` method isn't working.

Am I missing something?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Conan install will download the source if not present in your local cache. There a look here:

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#source

Running manually source, build and package, as the development flow, is not the same thing. It not necessary will work as using install command. There is a discussion about it here:

https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/5165

If you want to download from source again, remove your current package source:

```
conan remove -f <name/version@user/channel>
conan install <conanfilePath> -s compiler="Visual Studio" -s compiler.version=8 --build
```